Hacker is forced to access US Police information by his son's kidnappers
I am looking for an American movie in which a hacker is forced to access US Police information by his twelve year old son's kidnappers.

Do you remember anything else? Actors? Specific scenes? Was the movie old or new? When did you see it?

@Tom Yeah i got it its swordfish. Thanks for your reply.

Not at all. Glad you found it :)


The Movie Swordfish fits this description, albeit with a few discrepancies:

The Hacker's Daughter is taken hostage, although actress Camryn Grimes would have been 11 during the films production
It is a Bank that the Hacker (under duress) is forced to eventually infiltrate: although the Villians are a former counter terrorist cell doing this for revenge against the government (and reimbursement for supposed rendered service).

Earlier on in the film, however, Stanley is forced to infiltrate a government system.
From IMDB plot synopsis:

Gabriel pressures Stanley right-then-and-there to hack a government system in 60 seconds while at gun point and receiving oral sex.

That scene was a pretty unique part of the movie, if it included that its definitely Swordfish.
